# How to use ko.mapping in nested list return from server? knocknot.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to add data on fly in nested elements, problem is i want to convert each object returning from server to observable array..

```
function viewModel() {
    this.projects = ko.observableArray();
    this.addMember = function addMember() {
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.projects(), function (item) {
           // return the first item in the array just for simulation
           return true; 
        });
        if (match) {
            var newItem = {
                name: 'member 5'  
            };
            match.members.push(newItem);
        }
    };
}

var vm = new viewModel();
// manually declare observable
vm.projects.push({
    name: ko.observable('project a'),
    members: ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'member 1' },
        { name: 'member 2' }
        ])
});

vm.projects.push({
    name: ko.observable('project b'),
    members: ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'member 3' },
        { name: 'member 4' }
        ])
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

this is what i get for now :

http://jsfiddle.net/RyWr6/

in this example, i want to use ko.mapping for "List with all set object as array" without creating each object as observablearray

Comment: can you explain more what you want to actually do?

Comment: i want to add new item in nestedlist, using ka.mapping from knockout.js, go to my jsfiddle, and try to add new item using 2nd button

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create an observableArray for the members property. The only one solution is to change the project2 property manually.
As calling the valueHasMutated function on the project2 doesn't work, I will force the view to refresh by doing that :

```
this.addMember2 = function addMember() {
    var match1 = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.projects2(), function (item) {
       // return the first item in the array just for simulation
       return true; 
    });
    if (match1) {
        var newItem = {
            name: 'member 5'  
        };
        match1.members.push(newItem);
    }
    // trick
    var p2 = this.projects2();
    this.projects2([]);
    this.projects2(p2);
};
```

I know it's not a proper solution but I can't find a better one.

**Response to the question :**

The projects2 property doesn't contain observables elements. That means that ko engine wont be notified if something change in a nested element (like members).

In order to force the view refresh I change the projects2 property. By doing that the ko engine will be notified that someting changed in this property and refresh the view.

- p2 = this.projects2() : converts the observableArray() into regular array
- this.projects2([]) : this will cause the view refresh
- this.projects2(p2) : this adds the items I removed at the previous line and cause the view refresh

I hope it helps.

Comment: please, can you explain me those 3 lines

Comment: I modified the post to respond to your question.

Comment: Damien, your trick is good, but i am using some accordion panels and due to fresh the view, all panel are closed :( , so i think i still need something using ko.mapping ! :(